# Why using Steeltoe.Discovery.Client library in Asp.Net Core keeps increasing the memory?

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, dotnet-httpclient, netflix-eureka, steeltoe

I have a simple ASP.Net Core API 3.1 (from VS templates) project using Steeltoe.Discovery.Client 2.2.0 library. After a few days of running the application, the memory keeps increasing. I investigated a little bit to get some info about why the memory increased without using the app.

What I found is that for each call at 30 sec (HeartBeat askAsync, FetchRegistry Async) memory increase without decreasing.

Can someone help me figure out why memory keeps increasing (~1MB/min), at each I/O spike (eureka calls), without decreasing and how can I use it in production without restarting the app in order to release the memory?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Small barrage of questions if you don't mind: How high does the usage go? Are the communications with Eureka succeeding or failing? How many other app (instances) are registered with this server?

Answer (score 0):

In past releases, since 2.2.0, we have identified and resolved some issues that might be affecting you. Sounds like it might be related to the health checks. Can you try with the latest 2.4.4 release and see if you still have the issue? If not, we can take a closer look at your configuration and try to reproduce.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jason, I just made a test with latest version 2.4.4, the issue seems to be present also in this version.

Comment: We took a look and we think it might be related to the registry fetch. 
 Can you let us know what you have "registryFetchIntervalSeconds" set to?  Can you increase the value and see if that helps while we dig a little deeper?